# mvn clean install: failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler plugin:3.8.1 using intellij

Tags: java, maven, javafx, junit, testfx

when i'm running my code from intellij, it works fine, but when i'm using `mvn clean install`, these errors appear:
i'm using java 18.
I don't know what is wrong, I tried to add all dependencies and modules in the project structure, but it does not seem to find them.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) 

/src/main/java/module-info.java:[6,29] module not found: mysql.connector.java
/src/main/java/module-info.java:[7,16] module not found: org.testfx
src/main/java/module-info.java:[8,25] module not found: org.testfx.junit
```

this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>testfx-internal-java9</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.12-alpha</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=org.testfx
                    </argLine>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.40</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo/com.example.demo.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and my module-info.java

```
module com.example.demo {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires java.sql;
    requires mysql.connector.java;
   requires org.testfx;
    requires  org.testfx.junit;


    opens com.example.demo to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.demo;

   // exports com.sun.javafx.application;
}
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: The dependency `mysql-connector-java` is not even the most recent one nor  does it define a module as expected `mysql.connector.java`...that's the reason.. also you have defined `<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>` but `<source>18</source>` You should decide which one you will use either the property way or the explicit configuration of the plugin...

Comment: Do not manually add libraries to the IDE project. Ensure that all libraries are correctly defined as maven dependencies and synchronize the IDE project with maven to have it import the libraries automatically. That way IDE builds and maven builds are kept in sync, either both will pass or both will fail.